# sonarqube scanner on circleci

Tags: sonarqube, circleci, sonarqube-scan

I am using Sonarqube and CircleCI for code quality scan.
However, I don't know how if it is possible to start up a Sonarqube Server on CircleCI and use it to run the scanner.

This is my current `config.yaml`

```yaml
version: 2.1

executors:
  scanner:
    docker:
      - image: openjdk:11

commands:
  check-code-quality:
    description: Check Code Quality
    parameters:
      sonar_server_url:
        type: string
        description: "URL of your SonarQube server. e.g.: http://my.sonarqube,server:9000"
        default: "$SONAR_SERVER"
      sonar_login:
        description: "Authentication key (sonar.login paramter) to access SonarQube and perform analysis"
        type: string
        default: "$SONAR_TOKEN"
      sonar_sources:
        description: "Where the files are located?"
        type: string
        default: "$SONAR_SOURCES"

    steps:
        - run:
            name: Install Sonarqube scanner
            command: |
                wget https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-4.2.0.1873.zip
                unzip sonar-scanner-cli-4.2.0.1873.zip

        - run:
            name: Run Sonarscanner
            command: |
                export SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS="-Xmx2048m"
                eval ./sonar-scanner-4.2.0.1873/bin/sonar-scanner \
                -Dsonar.projectKey=projectKey
                -Dsonar.host.url=<< parameters.sonar_server_url >> \
                -Dsonar.sources=<< parameters.sonar_sources >> \
                -Dsonar.login=<< parameters.sonar_login >>

jobs:
  check-code-job:
    executor: scanner
    steps:
      - check-code-quality

workflows:
  check-code-quality-flow:
    jobs:
      - check-code-job:
          context: lineclass
```

There is an error log when the job being executed:

```java
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to get bootstrap index from server
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex(BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:42)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.getScannerEngineFiles(JarDownloader.java:58)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:53)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:76)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.R...
```

This indicates that the Sonarqube Server is missing.

If you have experience running sonar-scanner on CircleCI please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

After I change the image to `sonarqube:8.9-community` and fix the missing `\` in the `sonar-scanner` command (at the end of `-Dsonar.projectKey`), it works.